# DialogFlow knowlege articles not responding in Slack

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have enabled new feature of DialogFlow `Knowledge (beta)` and gave FAQ page link. Everything was setup correctly and its working fine in DialogFlow console.

I have also integrated my agent with Slack, where these FAQ are not being captured at all. Everything is going to `Default Fallback Intent`.

Is there any other step which I am missing to enable it for integrated clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control how much Dialogflow prefers Knowledge Base answer vs. intent answers with Knowledge bases setting slider.  Sliding toward the "stronger" (right) side will make it more likely to match Knowledge based answer instead of intent based responses: https://dialogflow.com/docs/knowledge-connectors#knowledge_connector_settings

Also, have you added a response in the Knowledge section?  If not go to

```
Knowledge > Knowledge Base > Responses
```

and click  and enter `$Knowledge.Answer[1]` in the response where you'd like to the Knowledge answer to appear
[image]
Note: you can also add platform specific messages here so make sure you have a response for you intended platform (e.g. Slack)

Comment: adding platform specific response solved the proble, everything else was setup already.